# Developing android app to grab images from a blog and display on mobile

Tags: android, image

Relatively new to android development, comfortable with basics.

I would like to grab images from a "tumblr" blog platform then display them images in a grid like layout on the mobile device.

My main problem is how I would go about scraping and parsing the images from tumblr. I'm at a loss at the moment and can't seem to find anything to put me in the right direction.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have the `tumblr API` that come to help you and back a json. In your specific case the [`photo-posts`](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#photo-posts) call.

The you just have to implement a call with the `HTTPClient` from [this package](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html) and parse the json, either by using the utilities from the [`org.json` package](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) or including some external lib like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: thankyou for that insight i now have a clear view of how i'm going to tackle this!

Can i clarify though, do i use a json array for the "photos" then another array inside for the size? but how do i distinguish the size? And how can i pass the URL into an image grid?